# preg_replace with patterns and named groups

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to learn how to use named groups properly and for some reason i dont know how to use **preg_replace** with named groups.

For example without named groups:

```
$str = som,ething;
$regex = '/(\w*)[^\w](\w*)/';
$replace = '${1}${2}';

preg_replace($regex, $replace, $str);
```

Output:

> something

But if I try to use named groups:

```
$str = som,ething;
$regex = '/(?<foo>\w*)[^\w](?<bar>\w*)/';
$replace = '${foo}${bar}';

preg_replace($regex, $replace, $str);
```

The output will be:

> ${foo}${bar}

Comment: have a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php

Comment: PHP doesn't support named references in the replacement text.

Comment: @stribizhev Argh! In the middle of writing a response and question was closed ... again. As anubhava said I don't think it works directly with preg_replace, however you could do something like the following: `preg_match('/(?<foo>\w*)[^\w](?<bar>\w*)/', 'som,ething', $matches);`  Then print the named parts: `print $matches['foo'].$matches['bar'];`.  You can also use `preg_replace_callback` which will respect the named groups.  `print preg_replace_callback("/(?<foo>\w*)[^\w](?<bar>\w*)/", "word_replace", 'som,ething');
function word_replace($matches) {return $matches['foo'].($matches['bar']);}`

Comment: @Quixrick: You can always add that as an answer to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for all @Quixrick, that was ver usefull.